# Zip list of files from terminal in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, zip

I'm using `Ubuntu Server` and i would `zip` a list of files contained in a directory called "`backups`".

So, using the `zip` command from command line, how can i do to zip all files with a name that starts with a particular prefix?

For example, I have these files:

- 2016hello
- 2015hello
- 2016good

I would zip only files with a name that starts with "`2016`".

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using an asterisk after 2016 - like this:

```
zip 2016archive.zip 2016*
```

you can learn more by typing in your terminal `zip --help`